# Inserting with empty values in PostgreSQL causes error

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

My table has three columns, but I'm only using one for most rows.

I'm trying to do a basic insert in PSQL, like so:

```
grouper=> INSERT INTO master_list VALUES ('Ebay',,);
```

But I'm getting a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: INSERT INTO master_list VALUES ('Ebay',,);
                                               ^
```

Any advice or suggestions welcome!

Comment: Yes.  List the columns in the `insert` statement.  Then you don't have to worry about empty values.

Comment: INSERT INTO lsa_loan_details (loan_number, repayment_type ) VALUES
 ('123456789','');  Say I want to insert EMPTY for repayment_type character varying(100), you can also specify two single quotes without space. it worked for me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO master_list VALUES ('Ebay',null,null);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO master_list (fieldname) VALUES ('Ebay');
```

Comment: huh, I'm surprised that a empty comma delimited field wouldn't be considered null automatically... this did work though, thanks!